# going through a loop inside regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a small function in python that will take a list of terminals and a string as inputs, and split the string by terminals. 
so say:

```
terminals=['true','/','false']
```

and:

```
string="false false/true"
```

output should be:

```
'false', 'false','/','true'.
```

I have trouble writing a regular expression, I don't know how to incorporate a loop that would go through every element of terminals

```
import re
def tokenize(terminals,stringline):
    tokens = [t for t in re.split(r"(\s+|true|false\|\)")]
```

can please give me any hints?

Comment: Where did the whitespace go in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use `re.findall` function instead of `re.split`.

```
>>> terminals=['true','/','false']
>>> string="false false/true"
>>> regex = '|'.join(terminals)
>>> re.findall(regex, string)
['false', 'false', '/', 'true']
```

OR

Use capturing groups in `re.split` regex to keep up the delimiters.

```
>>> string="false false/true"
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(true|false|/)|\s+', string) if i is not None and i]
['false', 'false', '/', 'true']
```

OR

```
>>> def tokenize(terminals,stringline):
        regex='|'.join(terminals)
        return [i for i in re.split('('+ regex + ')' +r'|\s+', stringline) if i is not None and i]

>>> terminals=['true','/','false']
>>> string="false false/true"
>>> tokenize(terminals, string)
['false', 'false', '/', 'true']
```